# Php Set TimeZone

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have following code:

```
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi'));  
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output: **2015-08-26 17:46:05**
Actual Result should be: **2015-08-26 13:46:05**

How to set the time zone, so that actual output comes?

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1 (Editing Php.ini)**

1) Open your php.ini file

2) Add the following line of code to top of your php.ini file

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Karachi"
```

3) Restart php.

Note: You can find a list of timezone here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

**Method 2 (Using date_default_timezone_set)**

In case you don't have access to the `php.ini` file, you can use `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi")`. Just put it in the entry point of your application.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: There is absolutely no need to change anything in the ini file

Comment: i have set the timezone . but it does not displaying actual time

Comment: @SobiaSafdar how did you set it?

Comment: @SobiaSafdar no problem

Answer (score 4):

use this line in your codes

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
```

like

```
  <?php 
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); 
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); 
?>
```

Comment: this is also showing a same result , not the actual one

Answer (score 1):

It is better to keep it in the config file because even if you use the same function somewhere else, you will have to re-declare this statement.

```
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
```

If you are using any framework like yii, CI or cake php.. keep this line in index.php file which basically later on loads rest of the framework.