# What can be the timezone and how we can set in php for Indonasia

Tags: php, timezone

We are setting the timezone in PHP as below for india and singapore

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

But for Jakarta i didn't manage to find the code for timezone.
can someone help to set jakarta timezone or particular bunch

Comment: `Asia/Jakarta` should be the timezone... it is in the [PHP Docs list of timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) between `Asia/Irkutsk` and `Asia/Jayapura`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Set TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222144/php-set-timezone)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
```

Check the [Php Timezone list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)